# Distribution Theory injective mapping proof

Tags: proof-verification, distribution-theory

The question is: $<g, \Phi>=0, \forall \Phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(X), \text{then } f=0.$ And the map $L_{loc}^{1} \rightarrow D'(X)$ where $D'(X)$ denotes the set of distributions on $X$, and $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an open set.

Attempt:

We can assume without loss of generality that $g \in L^{1}$ (since $L^{p} \subseteq L_{loc}^{1}, 1\leq p \leq \infty$). Now we know that $<g, \Psi>=0, \forall,\Psi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(X)$ by assumption.

Here is where I get stuck and don't really know how to proceed...

Comment: What is $g$? an element of $L^1_{loc}$?

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a famous lemma in analysis (which does not depend on the theory of distributions) that if $f\in L^1_{loc}(X)$, where $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\int_X f\varphi=0$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(X)$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere. 
It is not a trivial result, so it is normal that you cannot solve it as an exercise. See e.g. Corollary 4.24 in Brezis's *Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and Partial differential equations*.

The idea is that if you can choose $\varphi=\operatorname{sgn}f(x)\chi_K$ where $K\subset X$ is compact, then you get $\int_K |f|=0$ which implies $f=0$ a.e on $K$. Here $\operatorname{sgn}f(x)\chi_K$ is not a test function, but applying convolution with mollifiers you can approximate it with test functions which allows you to obtain the result.